# Zooming in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

[image: g]

[image]

I am wondering whether there is a possibility zoom to a certain location while the model is running (i.e while go procedure is active)
For the first part of my model I am mostly interested in what happening in the red box (First image). The second image is a zoomed version of the red box when i set gis:set-world-envelope "shape file with brown boundary".

However I will need to see the overall gis file (picture 1) as the model continues to run. Since my agents will start moving out of the red box.

Is there a way in netlogo to shift gis:world-envelope-of while the model is running or someway to zoom in and out.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: switch to 3D view.

**Long answer**: On your map, do a right click with your mouse. In the appearing context menu, select "Switch to 3D View". In the resulting view, you can zoom in with your mouse wheel on the blue center. If you need to move the center of view, click on "Move" (check screenshot below) button in the left bottom corner and replace your center of view, by holding the left mouse button and move of your mouse.

[image: **enter image description here**]